# Save local string from a function inside shared preferences and use it in other pages

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I wish to save the userid string that am getting from a function that parses and decodes JWT token , and be able to use it in other pages in my Flutter app . I tried to save it inside shared preferences but doesn't seem to be working .This is my function and how I used shared preferences

```
String userName;
dynamic authenticator;


String _decodeBase64(String str) {
  String output = str.replaceAll('-', '+').replaceAll('_', '/');

  switch (output.length % 4) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 2:
      output += '==';
      break;
    case 3:
      output += '=';
      break;
    default:
      throw Exception('Illegal base64url string!"');
  }

  return utf8.decode(base64Url.decode(output));
}

String _userid = '';

Map<String, dynamic> parseJwt(String token) {
  final parts = token.split('.');
  if (parts.length != 3) {
    throw Exception('invalid token');
  }

  final payload = _decodeBase64(parts[1]);
  final payloadMap = json.decode(payload);
  if (payloadMap is! Map<String, dynamic>) {
    throw Exception('invalid payload');
  }
  print(payload);


  addStringToSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _userid = payloadMap['user_id'];
    prefs.setString('stringValue',_userid );
  }


  //print(payloadMap['user_id']);

  return payloadMap;


}

getStringValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return String
  String _userid = prefs.getString('userid');
  print (_userid);
  return _userid;

}
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getStringValuesSF();
}




authenticate() async {
  // keyclock url : key-clock-url : example : http://localhost:8080
  // my realm : name of your real.m
  var uri = Uri.parse('http://169.254.105.22:8080/auth/realms/Clients');
  // your client id
  var clientId = 'helium';
  var scopes = List<String>.of(['openid', 'profile']);
  var port = 8080;
  var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
  var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);
  print(issuer.metadata);
  urlLauncher(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
  authenticator = new Authenticator(
    client,
    scopes: scopes,
    port: port,
    urlLancher: urlLauncher,
  );
  var c = await authenticator.authorize();
  closeWebView();
  var token = await c.getTokenResponse();
  var userInformation = await c.getUserInfo();
  setState(() {
    userAccessToken = token.accessToken;
    userName = userInformation.preferredUsername;
  });
  //print(token);
  //return token;
  parseJwt(userAccessToken);


}
```

I wish to use the userid variable here instead of the static string (id) am passing , in a way it dynamically reads the value from the function then use it inside the link to show the user's info :

```
  final response = await http.get('http://169.254.105.22:8093/user/v1/users/d374169b-c61f-4a5a-b00a-2a2a8d9c4e19');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load user');
  }
}
```

The second function is in another page (profile page), if anyone knows how I can save the userid from the function , then pass to another page (using sp or any other way) please don't hesitate to help thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when it comes to simple key/value storage, [GetStorage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage/install) is easier to use and less finicky than Shared Preferences. Try this:

Put this in your main before running your app.

```
  await GetStorage.init();
```

Then your `addStringToSF` method would look like this:

```
 addStringToSF() async {
    final box = GetStorage();
    _userid = payloadMap['user_id'];
    box.write('stringValue', _userid);
  }
```

Then from anywhere in your app access the stored value by

```
final box = GetStorage();
final newString = box.read('stringValue');
```

That should work for you.